# How do I make "10.0" return true while "10" return false

Tags: javascript

```js
function validateResponse(number) {
    console.log(typeof(Math.round(number)))
    console.log(typeof(number))
    if ((isNaN(number)) || (Math.round(number) !== parseFloat(number)))
        return true;
    else
        return false
    //checks if number is integer and checks for decimal places
}

let input = require("readline-sync");



console.log(validateResponse("10"));
console.log(validateResponse("10.0"));
```

I'm new to Javascript so my knowledge for it is limited. Correct me if I am wrong but does Javascript automatically convert "10.0" to a 10 if I did not use parseFloat?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the requirements of the function? Are you wanting to pass in a string, and then return true only if it includes a decimal point?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. But I think it is worth noting that JS doesn't have `float` and `int` types. Just `number` (that is, `float`, in practice). Integer are coded as `number` (which is exact, as long as they don't overflow mantissa)

Comment: My bad it seems I did not explain it properly. Basically, It is a function that prompts for the user's input which would be then passed into the (number)

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't automatically convert strings to numbers, but `Math.round(number)` and `parseFloat(number)` do.

Comment: `10.0` and `10` are just different ways of expressing *the same number*. It doesn't seem useful to distinguish between them. Why is your usecase?

Comment: So you are wanting to write a function that validates whether a user input can be converted to a number?

Comment: ask my teacher why cant 10.0 be valid...

Comment: "//lets say user inputs 10 for num1 and 10.0 for num2" — Instead of saying that, providing a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**: just hard code the variables to be those values).

Comment: _"How do I make "10.0" return true while "10" return false"_: `function validateResponse(number) { return number === "10.0"; }` returns `true` for `"10.0"` and `false` for `"10"`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Cheong — We can't. We don't have their contact details. Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). You've got what appear to be a **pointless and impractical task** designed to **test what you learned in class** — we don't know  what you are should have learned in class so can't demonstrate that. Probably you should be asking your teacher (not stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `includes(".")` method to test if the input contains a decimal point.
The full code would look like this:

```
function validateResponse(number) {
  const numberValue = parseFloat(number);

  return !isNaN(numberValue) && number.includes(".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your real requirements, but this would accomplish what you asked for. It checks whether the string of the number equals the string of the rounded number, and since 10.0 rounds to 10, they are not equal so it returns true, while 10 returns false.

```
function validateResponse(number) {
  return number.toString() !== parseInt(number).toString();
}
```